# bootstrap col-xs-* not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Never had this issue before. Go to [this website](http://quanjiaerp.azurewebsites.net/). As you can see, "sss" and "sssss" are put in two divs with class "col-xs-*". They should appear on same row, not sure why it's not working. 
[image]

Comment: You are using bootstrap wrong. All the `.col-*` classes should have a parent `.row`. [Check the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your "menuDiv" has float: left and that ruins the flow

either remove that, or add a float to the "mainDiv" as well

Answer (score 1):

as You are using XS-Xtra small , column type it will display as column on XS-devices for general use Use

```
<div class="col-7">your content
</div>
<div class="col-5">your content
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think that's the reason. col-xs-* works on extra small and larger devices, as col-md-* only works on medium size and larger devices.